# HTML5 video ended event not firing when video custom controls seekbar seeked to end

Tags: jquery, html, html5-video, custom-controls

I developed a custom **HTML5 video player** with **custom controls**( forward, backward, stop play and pause). I called the video **ended** function and displayed another html page when the video completes and it works fine in all browsers.

But when I try to seek the video using custom seekbar to end of the video, video **ended** function not firing in **IE9, IE10 and IE11** and works fine in **Chrome and firefox.**

I have googled it for so many times, but no results. plz provide any solution for this.

Below is the code which I have used for seekbar functionality,

```
   /* *********** HTML code *************************/
        <td id="tdSeekbar" style="cursor:pointer;">
            <input id="seek-bar" type="range"  title="Seekbar"  value="0">
     </td>
     <video autoplay id='objVideoPlayer' class='clsObjVideoPlayer' width='1024' height='576'>
<source src='" + strVideo.substring(1) + ".mp4' type='video/mp4'><object id='objVideoPlayer' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'  class='clsObjVideoPlayer'>
<param name='movie' value='Resources/VideoPlayer.swf' />
<param name='allowFullScreen' value='true' />
<param name='FlashVars' value='flv=" + strVideo + ".flv&amp;startimage=" + (strStartImage != "" ? strStartImage : "Images/Player/DefaultStartImage.gif") + "&amp;srturl=" + strSubTitles + &amp;configxml=Resources/VideoPlayer_Config.xml' />
</object>
</video>

    /**********Javascript code ***********************************/
     var seekBar = document.getElementById("seek-bar");
      video = document.getElementById("objVideoPlayer");

     // Event listener for the seek bar
    seekBar.addEventListener("change", function() {
        try {
        // Calculate the new time
           var time = video.duration * (seekBar.value / 100);
        // Update the video time
           video.currentTime = time;    
        }catch (Ex) { }
        });

    // Update the seek bar as the video plays
     video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        // Calculate the slider value
      var value = (100 / video.duration) * video.currentTime;
        // Update the slider value
        seekBar.value = value;
        });
    // Pause the video when the seek handle is being dragged
    seekBar.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            video.pause();
                });

    // Play the video when the seek handle is dropped
      seekBar.addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
            video.play();
        });

     function videoEnd() {
         try{

            instrHeader = " (Click below links to go to certain topic)";
            $("#instrTable").empty();
            $("#divInstrHeader").css('display','');
            $("#tdTitle").append("<span>"+instrHeader+"</span>");
            var len = eval("jsonInstructions." + videoName.replace(/\-/g, "_") + ".length");    
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++)
             $("#instrTable").append("<tr><td width='12px'>"+"&#187;"+"</td><td style='text-align:left;padding-left:3px;'><a class='topics-section' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick='" + "playVideo(" + eval("jsonInstructions." + videoName.replace(/\-/g, "_") + "[" + i + "].Time") + ")" + "'>"+ eval("jsonInstructions." + videoName.replace(/\-/g, "_") + "[" + i + "].Title") + "</a></td></tr>"); 

            $("#divVPToolbar").css("display", "none");   
            $('#tdVideoPlayer').hide();
            $('#topic-links').show();
            $("#imgFButtons").css("display", "").attr("src", "Images/UIFrame/BackMO.png").attr("onmouseover", "this.src='Images/UIFrame/BackME.png';").attr("onmouseout", "this.src='Images/UIFrame/BackMO.png';").attr("onclick", "JavaScript:LoadMovie('Flash','','','/TMContents.swf','');

$('#topic-links').css('display','none');
$('#tdVideoPlayer').css('display','');
$('#divInstrHeader').css('display','none');");
         }catch (Ex) {

         }
    }
     video.addEventListener('ended',videoEnd,false);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please share some code. We can't help you if you don't provide us anything else than "it doesn't work".

Comment: I checked the same seekbar 'ended' event with HTML5 default player instead of custom player controls in IE and may be the problem in IE browser itself and in other browsers it is working fine.

Comment: If anyone have faced the same problem, please post here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your current time in every update and  then check current time with duration if both are equal then perform your operation.

```js
window.setInterval(function(t){
    if(videoObject.currentTime == videoObject.duration)
    {
         //your code  
    }
    clearInterval(t);
 });
```